# Why are my Hibiscus leaves turning yellow?

Tags: hibiscus

I live on the coast of northern California, and my patio hibiscus is showing yellow leaves:
[image]
[image]

It has been hot lately (25-30C, >30% humidity), and I have been watering the tree every-other-day.